# Where is the 15068 PLATE W. BOW 2X2X2/3 in LDD?

Tags: piece-information, ldd

I can't seem to find this piece in ldd, and it's a very common piece.  I'm using the extended version.  where is it?

Answer (score 2):

Could not find it by typing numbers (15068 bricklink id or 605109 lego id) 
but simply browsing it is simple enough to find.

Open the 7th category of bricks, 4th element:
[image: plate with bow]
I'm using the latest ldd version (4.3.11)

Comment: I don't have the first two bricks, or the one I'm looking for!  I'm pretty sure I'm using the latest version too.  what's going on?

Comment: I'm using 4.3.12

Comment: hey, as a test, could you tell me the name of the first brick in the panel?  I'll try typing it in and seeing if I come up with anything.

Comment: @Millard - Did you enable the Extended mode (if that's still a thing in LDD)? That should load all the bricks rather than just a smaller set of common elements

Comment: I did, i don't know why this brick isn't showing up!  I see three bricks on Michael Verschaeve's picture that I don't have in that column.  I am using 4.3.12, and he is using 4.3.11. I wonder if that's the problem.

Comment: @Millard The latest version of LDD is missing a lot of parts for some reason. There's another question on here with links to the previous versions.

Comment: could you link it to me?  is it on the official lego site?

Comment: found it.  https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/12715/ev3-specific-bricks-missing-from-lego-digital-designer-4-3-11-win