# Identify this license plate holder piece

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, ldd, cad

Please tell me the name of this piece. I've been looking for it for hours on LDD and have tried searching for it with many names.

[image: some type of fender or car front piece]

I know that you use it for cars and it's a very common piece too.

The source of the picture is [this WikiHow article](https://www.wikihow.com/Build-a-LEGO-Truck), which contains no further description.

Comment: Hi Mark, which version of LDD are you using? There are [apparently some issues](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/12716/5853) with missing elements in the most recent version.

Answer (score 17):

There are two variant of that, which look very similar:

Stud.IO lists them as:

- Brick, Modified 2 x 4 - 1 x 4 with Recessed Studs and Thick Side Arches
- Brick, Modified 2 x 4 - 1 x 4 with Recessed Studs and Thin Side Arches

These can be seen below, thick in red on the left, and thin in blue on the right in the top picture (not a valid colour):

[image: Front and side view]
[image: Rear view with differences highlighted]

The difference is subtle but most visible on the side of the bottom, forward facing stud - the picture from the wikihow article appears to be using the Thin variant.

Answer (score 12):

This pieces is indeed hard to find, as it is used in building vehicles but does not have a name that has anything to do with that purpose. It is part number 52038 and is called [Brick, Modified 2 x 4 - 1 x 4 with 2 Recessed Studs and Thick Side Arches](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=52038&idColor=5#T=S&C=5&O=%7B%22color%22:5,%22iconly%22:0%7D) on Bricklink.

[image]

Comment: The one in the OPs picture looks more like "Brick, Modified 2 x 4 -1 x4 with 2 Recessed Studs and **Thin** Side arches"...

Comment: It is indeed hard to find, as the various databases can't agree on its size :) Brickset lists it as [BRICK 1X4X1 2/3 W. V. KNOBS
etc.](https://brickset.com/parts/design-52038), while on Bricklink the size is 2x4.

Answer (score 4):

Double nods to *Phil B.* and *Zhaph - Ben Duguid ♦* for offering correct answers, but *Mark Thrill* has provided further detail that might be a program issue, or he might have just said these words in jest.

> "I've been looking for it for hours on LDD..."

We know that certain versions of *LDD* do exclude pieces. The version of *LDD* that I'm using does have both variations of this piece.  So, *Mr. Thrill*, if possible can you check again to see if your version has these pieces:

If you just type "1x4x1" in *LDD's* search field, both variants should pop up underneath the subcategory brick image that's often used for a car's headlight.

[image]

Also could you please tell us what version of *LDD* you're using.

Help Menu> About (F3).

I'm using 4.3.11 in Extended Mode.

[image]

It might be nothing.  I know sometimes a piece's orientation gets rotated weird in the side tab of the program, and the piece we're looking for is right there in front of our eyes, but the inner mind's eye hasn't caught up yet.

So, both variants in *LDD* would be:

- (***Thicc***) *Part #52038 1x4x1 2/3 W. V. KNOBS.*
- (*Thin*) *Part #14520 1x4x1 2/3 W. V. KNOBS.*

Comment: Good point - I neglected to mention that I don't have LDD installed at the moment, and yes, it's also likely needing to be switched into "Extended Mode".

Comment: Possibly related, the last LDD update is missing a lot of pieces: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/12715/ev3-specific-bricks-missing-from-lego-digital-designer-4-3-11-win

Comment: Nope Zhaph, for this instance Extended Mode's omission of pieces has nothing to do with the program update omissions as Mr. O'mara has provided a link to.  Extended Mode offers no color restrictions to pieces, thus will show a piece's design only once, while Normal Mode will show a piece's design in all known colors that the piece has been sighted in the real world. Imagine a 1x1 brick. Extended will show it only once, while Normal will show it some 14 different times is every color it has known to appear in.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit of my answer, because it has changed the intended meaning/point that I've made.  As Alex has further pointed out the latest version 4.3.12 is garbage.  I myself have uninstalled it and gone back to using the 4.3.11. Again, It could still be nothing, but we're basically waiting on the OP to test for piece inclusion, and tell us what release he's using.  With all LDD questions that should be the first thing we need.  Please state your program version, kind Sir/Madame.

Comment: Good point about the version/modes as I don't have LDD installed any more I can't really comment either way. Probably better to add a comment asking for the version on the question, rather than deep down here ;)