# LDD lacks almost all functionality

Tags: ldd

I have installed LDD on my Windows 10 today, and after installing the application it automatically opened up. But I realized that when using the Desktop shortcut, the app can't be found. Here's the given error:

[image: application_not_found]

So I used the installer again, and it said that LDD was already installed. But I couldn't find the files anywhere, only the shortcut. So I reinstalled anyway and stored them in a directory I recognized, yet after installing when I checked the directory, **it wasn't there.** Once again I tried this process, but the problem persisted. I also notice that any LXF file I try to open doesn't do anything and LDD doesn't detect the file when I open it from the application itself. So LDD is quite crippled, tbh.

How do I solve this??

Comment: If you are on Windows 10 indeed, use Stud.io from Bricklink instead of LDD. LDD is no longer updated (since a few years already) and is missing newer parts. Stud.io is a much better product.

Comment: Unfortunately, we [can't really help with General Support for these applications](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), that's something you're better off raising with the supplier themselves. If you're sure you know where the installer was supposed to install the application and it's not there, I'd double check your AntiVirus software, and make sure that hasn't quarantined the executable. But as Phil B notes, [Stud.io](https://stud.io) is probably the way to go now.

Comment: Rather than re-installing, you should better go with full uninstall and then install again. This should remove all the associated files first and re-install correct ones, including the shortcut. Optionally, you could simply search for "ldd.exe" on your machine.

Comment: I have found a similar question that tells how to fix one of my problems: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279397/ldd-does-not-find-path-how-to-add

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update as of 12 January 2022

The LEGO Group has announced [via a press release](https://www.brothers-brick.com/2022/01/12/lego-fully-discontinuing-lego-digital-designer-in-favor-of-bricklink-studio/) they will be closing the LDD site from 31 January 2022, and encourage all users to migrate to Bricklink Studio.

> The LEGO Digital Designer (LDD) website will close on January 31st, after which time LDD will no longer be available for download. While downloaded versions of the LDD application will continue to work, people are encouraged to download BrickLink Studio, import their LDD files, and use Studio for 3D LEGO building files, and use Studio for 3D LEGO building.

### Original answer

As Phil B commented - you'd probably be better off with [Studio](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/download.page) now. This was originally developed by a team at BrickLink, and when they were acquired by The LEGO Group made [the following statement](https://www.bricklink.com/r3/announcement/lego_bl_faq.page):

> 7. What about Studio and LEGO Digital Designer (LDD) – what will happen with the two digital building experiences since they’re quite similar?
>    **The LEGO Group is planning to support and evolve Studio and will review opportunities for both services following the closing of the deal.**

So going forwards, Studio is the supported option. If you feel you really must stick with LDD, please also ensure that you use the last-but-one version, as the [very latest version is missing a number of elements](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/12716/56).

Finally, ensure that you download the installer from official sources (such as the LEGO CDN as linked in that answer), rather than "free software" sites, which might have tampered with the package.

Comment: Does it support LXF files? Might be a dumb question, but just wondering.

Comment: And is the studio hyperlink dangerous, or is it just my Antivirus getting confused?

Comment: I've fixed download URL. It is also easy to find it by googling "stud.io". It can also import LXF files, but not save them AFAIK.

Comment: Cheers Alex, and sorry @mindstormsboi : I assumed their short link was secure, and so shouldn't have linked it as https.

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Comment: TLG has announced that after 2022-01-31 the LDD website will be full removed and direct downloads from LEGO will no longer be available, nor will there ever be any more official updates to the software or the parts database. https://www.brothers-brick.com/2022/01/12/lego-fully-discontinuing-lego-digital-designer-in-favor-of-bricklink-studio/