# Has anyone noticed paint tool buttons missing?

Tags: ldd

In LDD version 4.3.10 I have found the four paint tool buttons to be missing. I searched online and haven't found anyone else with the same question, and the user's manual was no help. Then just playing around with LDD I noticed that if I open a free build in Extended Mode, the buttons are there, so then I have to import a model in order to use them. This is fine, but if anyone knows why the buttons would be missing in the first place, I'd appreciate hearing from them. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Bricks! LDD seems to have been end-of-lifed without there being an official announcement of it, other than The LEGO Group saying that they are now going to focus their efforts on Studio from BrickLink. If you have a large body of designs in LDD files, the good news is that Studio can open these, and it has a wider range of parts and features that LDD. More information and downloads: https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/download.page

Comment: Further checking shows that 4.3.10 [is officially unsupported now](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/ldd) - "Sorry. We don't support LDD version 4.3.10 anymore. If you still use version 4.3.10 you will experience errors when launching the application.". As noted on the linked question, version 4.3.12 also has missing parts, so you'll need to get the actual 4.3.11 version if you must stick with LDD on Windows.

Comment: Because it's no longer supported, LDD is bound to have strange problems. I've had a similar situation: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/ldd-lacks-almost-all-functionality