# LDD part library missing

Tags: ldd

I have deleted the LDD part database (part library) by mistake. 
As many of you know, LDD can no longer run in online mode, which means it can't update itself.

Is there any possibility to download the parts from somewhere or recover them somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [an archive of the LDD part library](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F-7JuE1XBn_HAtOlNlK0grcb8qD1Zca1) for you to download, but I am not certain if it works. Give it a try.

Alternatively, if that link ever breaks down and you have Windows 10 you can right-click on your recycle bin, press open, then right-click on the library file pending deletion and press restore. It will come back.

<sub>P.S. If you doubt you will ever use this feature again, you can disable it by right-clicking recycle bin, clicking "properties", and selecting "Don't move files to the Recycle Bin. Remove files immediately when deleted".</sub>

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much. You have no idea how happy you made me.

Comment: @alexvali You are welcome! If LDD ever stops working for any reason that seems impossible to fix then that means you should move on to Stud.io which is much more up-to-date and is still being worked on occasionally, and you can even make your own instructions there. See [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/ldd-lacks-almost-all-functionality) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I know about Stud.io and other 3rd party programs but I like the simplicity of LDD more and I don't have the patience for working in the others. It may sound strange but I actually like LDD's limitations for it makes me work around the problem. Thanks again and good luck sorting :))

Comment: Is there a more reputable source other than some random file from Google Drive?

Comment: @Alex I don't know because I actually copied the link from [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/14640/15028).

Comment: @alexvali - just so you know, The LEGO Group recently bought BrickLink and committed to supporting and evolving Stud.io in the future ([question 7 of the Acquisition secton](https://www.bricklink.com/r3/announcement/lego_bl_faq.page#Acquisition))