# What version of Lego Digital Designer has all the parts that LEGO ever added?

Tags: software, ldd

I would like to know what version of Lego Digital Designer has all the parts that the Lego company has ever added to the program, before the program was discontinued. I was able to find more parts from someone on Eurobricks forum but I still need more bricks.

Comment: Since LDD is discontinued there's always going to be issues with later parts not existing in there.  Stud.io or Mecabricks are more likely to continue getting new elements since they're still supported by their developers.

Comment: @chicks It might be worth referring to generic "LDraw based software" term rather than Stud.io specifically. Some like to use LDCad, MLCad and other software instead of Stud.io all of which use LDraw parts catalog.

Comment: do you guys know about any websites that are hosting bricks that can be manually added to Lego Digital Digital Designer

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the last version that had a complete set of elements was 4.3.11, however that has dependencies on Adobe Flash, so will likely not work on most modern systems that have now removed Flash.

The last release, 4.3.12 [has a known issue with missing parts](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/12715/56). However you can use the parts library (`Assets.lif`) from 4.3.11 with 4.3.12 - this can be extracted from the installer if you open it with an archive explorer (i.e. 7zip or similar).

Bear in mind that:

1. To see all the parts, you may need to enable "Extended Mode" (View | New themes | extended).
2. LEGO Digital Designer is no longer actively supported. However The LEGO Group have purchased the team [behind Studio](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/download.page), which is actively developed and has new parts regularly added.

Edit to add:

Glad you've managed to get it working in your preferred version. I'm not aware of people adding more elements to the official library files, but I've not really looked for it.

Whilst we can't say exactly what The LEGO Group will do in the future, they did say when [they acquired BrickLink that](https://www.bricklink.com/r3/announcement/lego_bl_faq.page):

> The LEGO Group is planning to support and evolve Studio and will review opportunities for both services following the closing of the deal.

They also released a [video last December (2020)](https://youtu.be/YxUIdvkHt4Q?t=225) where they updated on the future of both BrickLink and Studio.

> In addition, we're going to upgrade the Studio software every month to improve the user experience and enhance it's performance.

Finally, as a quick test, I was able to find the [Fright Knights Witch and Bat Lord](https://brickset.com/sets/6031-1/Fright-Force) heads and torsos fairly quickly in Studio:

[image]

Others are likely available.

Comment: i was able to bypass the adobe flash installer by using 7 zip to open it the i opened the lif file and copied all the bricks from 4.3.11 to the verison 4.2.5

Comment: i only use the version 4.2.5 because its not as old but it still allows me to add more parts without crashing as much (it also allows me to take screenshots, in the newer versions, the Lego Company removed the feature like 4.3 and higher

Comment: is it possible the that Lego Company might start working on Lego Digital Designer Again like continue adding more bricks and fixing crashes (i don't know why they stopped working on it, its so easy to use (what does the Lego Company seriously have to do thats more important then to work on their program) (they are beginning to have a reputation like Microsoft)

Comment: i would also highly appreciate anyone that can add the heads from the old castle lego themes (Fright Knights (Fright Knights are my favorite) Dragon Knights, etc)

Comment: is it possible i can go the studio app and add the heads to Lego Digital Designer

Comment: Seeing as those are "decorations" on the base "head" element, they should be vaguely easy to locate .png and add the details to a `DecorationMapping.xml` file.